# Decipher and parsing protocol and url from packet payload

Tags: c, packet

We are using pf_ring to capture packets. We are able to decipher information like source and destination ip, mac etc from the header information. Now we are moving into payload to decide the type of protocol, url and other information. We see that tcpdump and wireshark have done good parsing. I have download tcpdump but cant find where is the parsing done to find out the application protocol and url. I know it exist so we dont want to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: Are you talking about the source code of `tcpdump`?

Comment: yes if there is any module where I can refer too?

Comment: Yes any other modules to look into ?

Comment: Why don't you set up a filter according to your needs in `tcpdump` and save the result in a file and parse the file instead?